# How to select object_definition(object_id) for table in sql using C#?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 question.

This query is for display script store procedure as create to query

Query :

```
  Select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects
  where type_desc in ( 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')
```

I can display script of all store procedure.

Question 1 : I have TestStoreProcedure in store procedures.How can I display for only TestStoreProcedure.How can I use like this :

```
    Select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects
  where type_desc in ( 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')  and ??? =TestStoreProcedure
```

Question 2 : How can I use this query for tables or for defined table ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved for tables(create script of defined table name)

```
 declare @vsSQL varchar(8000)

 declare @vsTableName varchar(50)

 select @vsTableName = 'tblLocation'

 select @vsSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @vsTableName + char(10) + '(' + char(10)

 select @vsSQL = @vsSQL + ' ' + sc.Name + ' ' +  st.Name +

 case when st.Name in ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar') then 

 '(' + cast(sc.Length as  varchar) + ') ' else ' ' end +

 case when sc.IsNullable = 1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end + ',' + char(10)

 from sysobjects so

 join syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id

 join systypes st on st.xusertype = sc.xusertype

 where so.name = @vsTableName

 order by

 sc.ColID

 select substring(@vsSQL,1,len(@vsSQL) - 2) + char(10) + ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, to restrict the output of `OBJECT_DEFINITION` you would do

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) From sys.objects where name='TestStoredProcedure'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE sp_helptext proc_name   --<-- Without schema name
```

Comment: This is not usefull.It gives many rows.But my code gives a row for a sp